# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable while trying to assign a loop list into variable

Tags: python

I was trying to insert a new record of data  to my MySQL database into column 'username' & 'password'. In my case there's two assigned variables: `n0` and `n1` both variable stored the data I wanted to insert, `n0` stores 3 string while `n1` stores a 3 randomly generated integer, take a look of my code:

```
import mysql.connector 
import numpy as np

db = mysql.connector.connect (
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    password='######',
    database='python_database'
)

cursor = db.cursor()

syntax = "INSERT INTO information VALUES(%s,%s);"

n0 = ['Player ' + str(i) for i in range(3)]
n1 = [p for p in (np.random.randint(1,1000,3))]
for i in range(3):
    values = (n0[i],int(n1[i]))
    cursor.execute(syntax,values)
    db.commit()
```

When I executed the file my console throws this: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Full traceback:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\USER\Documents\DSProject\database.ipynb Cell 1' in <cell line: 15>()
     11 cursor = db.cursor()
     13 syntax = "INSERT INTO information VALUES(%s,%s);"
---> 15 n0 = ['Player ' + str(i) for i in range(3)]
     16 n1 = [p for p in (np.random.randint(1,1000,3))]
     17 for i in range(3):
```

(If anyone got a better title, please tell me in the comment)

Comment: Is this the whole code? As is, it doesn't seem to generate that error. Are you perhaps overwriting `str` or `range` somewhere with an int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere else in your code you have something that looks like this:

```py
range = 5
```

or maybe

```py
str = 10
```

that is interpreted as meaning a function call on the object bound to `range` or `str`, which is an `int`. And that fails.

Comment: Yes I'd have added `range = 3` to my code but I have already deleted it yet its still occurring?

Comment: Ok nevermind that, I restarted my text editor and it executed with no error, thanks!